# Not sure how to add "POST" query parameters to "Add custom search engine" extension in Firefox

Tags: firefox, search-engines

I'm currently trying to add [AZLyrics](https://www.azlyrics.com/) to my list of available search engines in Firefox, using the [Add custom search engine](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-custom-search-engine/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search) extension by Tom Schuster.

Searching for "test" in AZLyrics yields the following URL: https://search.azlyrics.com/search.php?q=test&x=fe974a6b00193a2c0334a5d250bd1f34caa2f051c628ccd002cdb7918cf391e0

As you can see, there is a string of characters which follows the search term. Must I then check the "Use POST query parameters" option in the "Add custom search engine" extension? If so, I'm not sure what to put in that field.

Running Firefox 116.0b1 (64-bit) under GNU/Linux Debian Bullseye (11) AMD64.